# Is it true that the set of all 0-1 sequence with no two consecutive 1 is uncountable

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, alternative-proof, combinatorics-on-words

My answer is yes. It is true that the set of all 0-1 sequence with no two consecutive 1 is uncountable.
Because think about it in the situation of coin tossing that either head or tail appearing with the probability of 1/2. And use indicator function $1_s$, S={the tossing is head}, then it is a normal 0-1 sequence because any 0-1 word of length n appearing with a limiting frequency $1/2^{n}$ and now translate the set of normal 0-1 sequence into normal numbers in binary system, then the set of normal numbers will form a full measure in [0,1], then it is uncountable. (I don't know if this step is valid or not, the set of full measure is uncountable?)

Comment: But if the word $11$ cannot occur, the sequence isn't normal.

Comment: Hi I am also in doubt. But here is the sentence I saw from Wiki talking about normal number, "A normal number can be thought of as an infinite sequence of coin flips (binary) or rolls of a die (base 6). Even though there will be sequences such as 10, 100, or more consecutive tails (binary) or fives (base 6) or even 10, 100, or more repetitions of a sequence such as tail-head (two consecutive coin flips) or 6-1 (two consecutive rolls of a die), there will also be equally many of any other sequence of equal length. No digit or sequence is 'favored'"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: @AJY But you are "right", I also don't know how to justify this for myself. Really wish someone having idea can explain about this.

Comment: For a binary sequence $(s_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ (and you can figure out how to rephrase it for a number to be normal in base $2$), we say that $(s_k)$ is *normal* if given any binary block $\mathbf{b} = ( b_1, \ldots , b_n )$, we have that $\lim_{k \to \infty} N( \mathbf{b} , k ) / k = 2^{-n}$, where $N( \mathbf{b}, k) = \# \{ j \leq k : s_{j} = b_{1} , \ldots s_{j + n - 1} = b_{n} \}$. That is, the frequency of any binary block is proportional to its length.

Comment: So for any sequence where $11$ never occurs, the block $11$ has frequency $0$ where it should have frequency $1/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ one-to-one onto your set: for any sequence $s$, $f(s)$ is obtained from $s$ by replacing each $1$ by $1,0$.
 Thus e.g. $f([0,1,1,0,0,1\ldots]) = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0\ldots]$.
Thus your set has the same cardinality as $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, namely $\frak c$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is brilliant! It reminds me of the proof of Cantor set is uncountable. Replace the decimal's digits of the end points of every interval of Cantor set 2 with 1 to construct the surjective mapping with normal numbers in [0,1]. What you mean by  is Cantor set, right? Because Cantor set has the same cardinality as [0,1] and since the set of my event also has the same cardinality as [0,1], so these three have the same cardinality, right?

Comment: $\frak c$ is standard notation for the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).  As you say, it is the cardinality of the Cantor set, and of $[0,1]$.